# Inequalities - Interval Notation Question

Tags: calculus

I have two solutions to two different homework questions and I am just a little confused in regards to they way both intervals are formated.

I am asked to solve the inequalities below:

1) |2x| ≥ 4

The solution: [2, ∞] U [-∞, -2]

2) x^2 < 2

The solution: (-√2, √2).

I was just wondering why the solution to 2) isn't (-√2, ∞) U (-∞, √2). Would both answers be considered acceptable?

Okay here's another example with a less than or equal to sign.

|t-1| ≤  3

The answer: [-2, 4].

That question is nearly identical to question 1, I don't understand why this particular question is formated that way too?

Comment: It would be acceptable with $\cap$ instead of $\cup$. Otherwise your set would equal all of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to describe where $x<\sqrt{2}$ AND $x>-\sqrt{2}$.

That is, $(-\infty,2)$ AND $(-2,\infty)$

You have to use the intersection $∩$ of both sets to get the desired overlap.

Comment: Hi, I understand your explanation, but this example also uses an equal to/or sign:
|t-1| ≤ 3.
The answer: [-2, 4].

That question is nearly identical to question 1, I don't understand why this particular question is formated that way too?

Comment: You want both $t-1 \leq 3$ and $-(t-1) \leq 3$. This comes out to $t\leq4$ and $t\geq-2$.

Comment: You have $(-\infty, 4] \cap [-2, \infty) = [-2,4]$